# Controlling Multiple Views in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am very new to Windows programming but have a lot of experience in Mac OSX and iOS programming. I am creating my first Windows application and have run into an issue. I have a Windows Form Application with three views on the form from left to right. The first one is a TreeView and the other two are ListViews. I would like each view to have its own class to handle the data and events for each view. In my Mac app I would create three view controller classes (with nibs) and just add those to the main view.

What is the correct way to do this in a Windows Form Application?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and programming in C# if that makes any difference.

Comment: look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367126/console-application-code-to-windows-form-c-sharp#comment21713851_15367126)

Comment: Yep, I realized that WinForms is outdated after submitting this question and restarted my project using WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I recommend here is that you take a look at MVP (Model View Presenter) pattern, there are two major flavors of it: Supervising Controller and Passive View.

Basically, you are already familiar with MVC patterns by introducing these controllers, and it is the same thing here, principles are always the same ;)

Maybe you are expecting a library or a tool to do this automatically for you, well ... bad news maybe :) I never used such "tools" since I like to have full control of these things, and they are not overly complex as well. There are certain MVP frameworks that you can use which would implement some things for you, but again, I never used any of these for WinForms, and I know that most of these are outdated very much.

Maybe you should consider trying out WPF instead of WinForms?

Comment: WPF is the way to go. Thanks for the help.